# Passing a struct trough a pipe in C

Tags: c, pipe

Consider the following struct:

```
struct msg { 
   int id;
   int size;
   double *data;
}
```

Now, this struct is to be used to communicate trough a pipe between a Producer and a Consumer processes.

As it is, it won't work, due to the `data` pointer... so it must be changed to actual data (not the pointer to data). But the complication arises from the fact that Producer **must be able to send ANY amount of data** (and receiver... works accordingly).

Does any one can, please point me a solution?
Specifically:

- What is the best solution for defining the data structures?
- Is  union with a `char* c_data` (passing it to the write) the way to go?
- How to implement `read` for accounting the size?

Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: You can't transfer pointers between processes on modern protected systems. A pointer is private to a single process, and can't be used by a different process (not even if it's started from the same executable program).

Comment: Write a serialize and deserialize functions, that would convert the structure to something abstract your can read on the other end. You could even convert your data to a string `"123 456 789.123"` and send that and use `printf`/`scanf` functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The question acknowledges that and states the OP seeks to send the `double` data (presumably an array of them at the location), not the `double *` value.

Comment: You can simply write to the pipe the contents of `id`, the contents of `size`, the contents of a `size_t` (or other integer suitable for you) that contains the number of `double` values being sent (assuming that is not what `size` already is) and then the `double` values. As long as you are writing to a process using the same object representations, you can send the raw bytes of the `double` objects; there is no need to serialize them specially. In the receiver, read the values for `id`, `size`, and the number of `double` items, then read the specified number of `double` values.

Comment: You've already got a `size` element in the array.  It seems like you want to use the old style VLA and do `struct msg{ int id; size_t size; double data[0]; }`

Comment: ...but more likely you just want a proper serialization/deserialization.  Using the VLA struct hack is probably not the way to go.

Comment: In the meantime I have reached the solution presented by @Eric Postpischil. It seem to me the most elegant and simple, even in the case of multiple Producers/Consumers, where some care must exit for achieving exclusive access during write/read. Building a serializer seems to me more opaque... and even prone to other errors. Still open to comments and opinions. :) THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

There unfortunately is no native way of sending arbitrary objects through a pipe. However, you can achieve what you want pretty easily by sending raw data with the help of [`fread()` and `fwrite()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) as a very simple way of serializing the data in binary form.

Please keep in mind that in order for the following to work, both the producer and the consumer programs need to be compiled on the same machine, using the same data structure definitions and possibly the same compiler flags.

Here's a simple solution:

1. Create a common definition of an header structure to be used both by the producer and the receiver:

   ```
   struct msg_header { 
       int id;
       int size;
   };
   ```

   This will hold information about the real `data`. I would suggest you to use `size_t` to store the size, as it is unsigned and more suitable for this purpose.
2. In the *producer*, prepare the data to be sent along with the correct header, for example:

   ```
   struct msg_header header = {.id = 0, .size = 4};
   double *data = {1.23, 2.34, 3.45, 4.56};
   ```

   It doesn't obviously need to be declared like this, it could even be dynamically sized and allocated through `malloc()`, the important thing is that you know the size.
3. Still in the *producer*, send the header followed by the data through the pipe:

   ```
   // Use fdopen() if you don't already have a FILE*, otherwise skip this line.
   FILE *pipe = fdopen(pipe_fd, "w");

   // Send the header through the pipe.
   fwrite(&header, sizeof(header), 1, pipe);

   // Send the data through the pipe.
   fwrite(&data, sizeof(*data), header.size, pipe);
   ```
4. In the *consumer*, read the header and then use the `.size` value to read the correct amount of data:

   ```
   // Use fdopen() if you don't already have a FILE*, otherwise skip this line.
   FILE *pipe = fdopen(pipe_fd, "r");

   struct msg_header header;
   double *data;

   // Read the header from the pipe.
   fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, pipe);

   // Allocate the memory needed to hold the data.
   data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * header.size);

   // Read the data from the pipe.
   fread(&data, sizeof(*data), header.size, pipe);
   ```

Keep in mind that you have to *check for errors* after each of the above function calls. I did not add error checking in my examples just to make the code simpler. Refer to the manual pages for more information.